# Chart Web Part in SharePoint 2013 - Pie chart counting each task individually instead of grouping like tasks together?

Tags: 2013, 2010, chart-web-part

I was able to get the 2010 Chart Web Part to "work" in SharePoint 2013, but I'm having an issue getting the charts to work the way I want them to.

I'm trying to create a pie chart that shows the percentage of tasks that are in a certain status (open, not started, in progress, etc.). However, the chart seems to be taking each task INDIVIDUALLY and giving it a piece of the chart. So, right now I just have a chart that says Not Started over and over again (there are over 100 tasks, so there's not actually room to include all of them).

I connected the chart to the appropriate list and made the Y field Total and the X field Status. I'm really not sure what I need to do, at this point, to make it work properly.

Comment: Microsoft did hide/remove the web part for a reason. Mayby if you export the list to an Excel sheet and create a pivot there and then upload/embed the excel to the page instead?

Comment: Nevron Chart for SharePoint is a pretty simple way to make charts - http://support.nevron.com/KB/a166/count-number-items-a-column-using-sharepoint-chart-pivot.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use a different approach.

Try use CSOM to read the data from lists and [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create the graphs.

Sample: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-a-chart-using-chartjs-in-sharepoint-server-2013